# I can hardly calculate how often 'calculation' is used as an uncalculated risk of having a meaningless question title

Tags: discussion, buzzwords, site-cleanup

Hello again from buzzword land!

I have recently been looking through some of the buzzword queries again and noticed, that there is again (still) lots to do. Very helpful in this regard is [Brian's SEDE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/chemistry/query/654396/questions-possibly-with-chem-se-buzzwords-in-the-title). Today I would like to add a few more entries to the list, although I know that these buzzwords are borderline, since they have  legitimate use: **calculation**, and **calculate**.

I am talking about gems like [Calculate the Oxidation Number](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/42133/4945), [Calculate the Molarity of a soln](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14196/4945), [Bond Energy Calculation](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/37455/4945), [Calculation of CFSE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/28976/4945), ... , the list goes on.
If you want to take a stab at them, search for ['calculate'](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Acalculate), ['calculating'](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Acalculating) and ['calculation'](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3Acalculation) in question titles on the main site.

We would be very grateful, if you want to help out a little and earn some flags and edits. If you would like to know more about the [buzzwords](/questions/tagged/buzzwords), look at other questions in that tag, for example [sorting them with newest first](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/buzzwords?sort=newest&pageSize=50).

Comment: Ok, well, I added them regardless, with an option for excluding based on score.

Comment: And I expanded the exclusion options, so that one can narrow down to just a particular buzzword if desired.

Comment: And wow, yeah, *calculat** is a really common offender.

Comment: An incalculable number!

Comment: @M.A.R. I left that out this time, because it is covered by Brian's SEDE query, which does a far better job than the built-in search (especially since you cannot sort the results with ascending score).

Comment: the word calculation is not meaningless. It tells you that the question is not conceptual but practical.

Comment: @HernanMiraola That is technically not correct and you could find that out by looking at high-voted questions with these titles. I also specifically gave examples in which cases the title is completely meaningless and where it acts as a buzzword and should therefore be removed. Just to name one example: [Why are solids and liquids not included in the equilibrium constant? What about in a reaction rate calculation?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14058/4945) This is a conceptual question, where *calculation* is basically not avoidable and has a specific meaning.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン well I didn't see all titles but see the first and it was about a calculation...; also I see the second and  it is also about a calculation..; and the third.

Comment: @HernanMiraola Yes, that is correct, but you cannot tell what the question is about beyond that. Therfore the title is completely arbitrarily and meaningless. Hence the word *calculation* is only there because you have to enter something in the title field - and it is possibly one of the broadest terms that is in use here. And therefore it is not at all helpful.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン not beyond that, but you know it is not a conceptual question. It is just fine for me at least. But you may know it better..

Comment: @HernanMiraola I really do not understand your last comment. I also never said anything about the questions themselves. I am simply arguing that they should have a descriptive title so that they will be easy to find in the future, especially for new users. Whether or not they are conceptual or practical or anything in between is a completely different issue and has nothing to do with the quality of a question title.

Comment: Sorry @Martin-マーチン . I am just repeating what i said. The word calculation is not meaningless. it tells you that the question is not conceptual but practical. Maybe you are too focused on the meaning of each word, but the word calculation is useful, at least for me.

Comment: @HernanMiraola I would like to encourage you to write your concerns as an answer so that it is more visual.

Comment: Martin I guess having both linked wouldn't hurt. @HernanMiraola "calculation" is of course not meaningless because you can find it in a dictionary, but it makes for a very poor question title; because it gives the OP the feeling that they have done the title justice, but they haven't. There's a much better title that can help me find that specific question than "pls calculate entropy", and "calculate X" does not tell me what's special about the specific question.

Comment: @M.A.R. +1 for your kindness. I know there exist dictionaries. Just a thought: OP is your enemy? \\ Take my comment as an opinion: it gives information about the post..What information? Well, if you don't know the meaning of calculation just search it on a dictionary; if you know the meaning, you are being adviced that the question is not conceptual but practical.

Comment: @Hernan OP is Original Poster, sorry for being too lazy to type it out. My point is that even if, as you suggested, "calculation" would indicate the question is practical, that's hardly what a title is capable of telling us. A title should ideally lead you to that specific question when you type it into Google. "entropy calculation" wouldn't lead you to that question in a million years.

Comment: @M.A.R. Yes, but if you write "How to calculate oxidation number" number you will get what you want. Maybe the title could be better but in a huge number of posts it is just good.

Comment: @HernanMiraola I doubt that; because I get [56 results](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=how+to+calculate+oxidation) from Chem.SE, let alone Google. Not even "how to calculate oxidation number" is specific enough.

Comment: @M.A.R. I am sorry but it seems simple for me. Anyway, ten upvotes would mean I am wrong. So, make the changes..or what you wanna do.

Comment: @Hernan the only problem here is your expectations of what makes a good title are different from the expectations of the rest of the community. They'd  readjust themselves once you have hopefully stuck around and gained more experience on how to moderate in Chem.SE. :)